# Deploying Xamrin forms app on Apple store

Tags: ios, iphone, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I have a Xamarin forms project on my Windows machine that I need to deploy on the iOS App Store.

I have an Apple developer account registered already.

Can someone explain this steps to deploy this as I am new to Xamarin?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/deploy-test/app-distribution/app-store-distribution/publishing-to-the-app-store?tabs=vsmac

Comment: I have gone through this link already . This is not going to hep out !

Comment: You asked for the steps to deploy an app.  Those are the official steps.  It might be helpful if you explained what specific problem you have when trying to follow them.

Comment: It is possible to deploy directly to a device using [Free Provisioning for Xamarin.iOS Apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/get-started/installation/device-provisioning/free-provisioning)

Comment: Do you have a Mac for building your iOS App?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Microsoft App Center (https://appcenter.ms) for test or deploy it on the Apple AppStore/GooglePlay stores.